# My form (form_for) is ONLY saving under my current_user the first time. The rest are not attached to the current_user but they are persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I am building a donation web application, and I am confused as to why the form only saves to my current_user on the first donation.  If I go to the same recipient and add an integer to any given category  (create a new donation), it will not be saved under the current_user but it does save in the DB.  Here is the pertinent code:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @category = current_user.categories.new
end 


def create
    @category = current_user.categories.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
        redirect_to donor_interface_path
    else
        render 'categories/_form', alert: "Your donation was not saved."
    end
end

def edit
    @category = Category.find_by(params[:donor_id])
end

def update
    @category = Category.find_by(params[:donor_id])
    if @category.update(category_params)
        redirect_to donor_interface_path
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

Form_For

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
<%= hidden_field_tag :category_id, @category_id, class: "form-control" %> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :toilet_paper %><br>
<%= f.text_field :toilet_paper, class: "form-control" %></div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :dental_hygiene %><br>
<%= f.text_field :dental_hygiene, class: "form-control" %></div>
```

On both edit/new pages

```
<%= render "categories/form", category: @category %>
```

ApplicationController showing current_user code

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= Donor.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

AR

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipients
    has_many :donors, through: :recipients

class Donor < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipients
    has_many :categories, through: :recipients**strong text**

class Recipient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :donor
    belongs_to :category
```

Comment: Add your `category_params` method and an example of the submitted params. Could  it be that you're assigning `user_id` from the params?

Comment: He Max, in this case, it would be donor_id, and I was not submitting the donor_id through the params.  To be honest, I have attempted to manually add the donor_id through the params, add some type of belongs_to relationship to the donor and try to track all the donations that way.

It is so crazy that I can't figure out why only the form that is created a the time of the recipient is showing up under my current_user.  Every other form is obviously not tied to anything... I am missing something simple, but frustratingly enough, very elusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find or create the relationship between your `Donor` (current_user) and your new/update `Category` through the recipients table.

You can do something like :

```
 def create
  @category = current_user.categories.new(category_params)
  if @category.save
    @category.recipients.find_or_create_by(donor_id: current_user.id, category_id: @category.id)
    redirect_to donor_interface_path
  else
    render 'categories/_form', alert: "Your donation was not saved."
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this will be perfect!  When I get to my laptop tonight, I will try it immediately.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have one more question for you!  Can you give me a clue as to how I can return ONLY the categories created by the donor (current_user).  It seems so dang obvious but I can't get what I need...

Comment: @TylerP3358 `donor.categories` usually do the job

Comment: Yeah... I know.  I'm missing something though.  Donor.categorizes only returns the initial donation still!  I do create a category form at the time of recipient creation.  I need to rethink it I think.  Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: One major gotcha here is that you're not checking if `find_or_create_by ` actually succeeds. Either use `find_or_create_by!` or a conditional so it does not just fail silently.

Answer (score -1):

In create action try with the **build** method

```
   def create 

      @category = Category.new(category_params)
      @category = current_user.categories.build(category_params)
         if @category.save
           redirect_to donor_interface_path
         else
           render 'categories/_form', alert: "Your donation was not saved."
         end
   end
```